# Javascript - trying to do reference passing with recursive calls

Tags: javascript, recursion, memcpy

In the context of a 2 players game, I have a C function that does recursive calls and for each call, it does a `memcpy` from a global array variable a current local array. Here's this C function ("**game**" array is declared as a global variable, outside the function) :

```
int game[8][8];

int recursive_function(int player, int *mx, int *my, int depth)                           

{                                                                                        
  int x, y;
  int eval, e;                                                                           
  int mx2, my2;                                                                          
  int game2[8][8];

  // TERMINAL CASE
  if (depth == 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  memcpy(game2, game, sizeof(game));                                                     
  eval = -INFINITY;                                                                        

  for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)       
    for (y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
      if (isplayabe((x, y, player)) {                                                    
        e = -recursive_function(OTHER(player), &mx2, &my2, depth-1);                          
      }
      if (e > eval) {                                                                    
        *mx = x; *my = y;
        eval = e;
      }                                                                                  
      memcpy(game, game2, sizeof(game));                                                 
      }                                                                                  
  return eval;
}
```

Now, I would like to implement the same function in javascript.

I think I have to use object for reference passing. So I have created objects `Hit` and `HitTemp` with for each of them, coordinates of array as attributes :

1. `Hit.coordPlaybles` are `(x,y)` coordinates and makes the link as the equivalent of `game` variable above
2. `HitTemp.coordPlaybles` are `(x,y)` coordinates and makes the link as the equivalent of `game2` variable above

From this, I tried with Object `Hit` defined by :

```
// Player white and black
var playerWhite = ['white', 'black'];
var playerBlack = ['black', 'white'];

var Hit = {
 currentPlayer: playerBlack,
 coordPlayable: ['0', '0'],
 coordCurrent: ['0', '0'],
};
```

The object `Hit` is declared outside recursive_function (global variable) whereas `HitTemp` is defined only into this function (local variable).

Here is what I did :

```
// Object Hit passed by reference
function recursive_function(Hit, depth) {
  // Evaluation
  var eval, e;

   // TERMINAL CASE
      if (depth == 0) {
        return 1;
      }

  // Local Hit object : EQUIVALENT OF "memcpy" ??
  var HitTemp = Object.assign({}, Hit);

  eval = -infinity;       

  for (var x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    for (var y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
      if (isplayabe((x, y, HitTemp)) { 
        // CALL RECURSIVE WITH OPPOSITE PLAYER (SWITCHING PLAYER)                                                   
        e = -recursive_function(OTHER(HitTemp.currentPlayer), depth-1);  
        if (e > eval) {
                  // HitTemp.coordCurrent[0] = *mx
                  // HitTemp.coordPlayable[0] = x
                  // HitTemp.coordCurrent[1] = *my
                  // HitTemp.coordPlayable[1] = y
                  HitTemp.coordCurrent[0] = HitTemp.coordPlayable[0];
                  HitTemp.coordCurrent[1] = HitTemp.coordPlayable[1];
                  eval = e;
                }
   // Final copy from HitTemp to Hitobject : Here also, equivalent to 
   // the final memcpy of C version ??
   Hit = Object.assign({}, HitTemp);
  }
return eval;
}
```

Unfortunately, the results between the 2 versions are quite different (I am sure that C version is working fine).

Could anyone tell me if the Javascript "`assign`" method is the right method to reproduce the behavior of C "`memcpy`" function ?

If not, could you give me some clues to fix it with recursive calls?

**UPDATE 1 :**

Thanks for your help. However, I have an issue with solution suggested by 
@Siltaar . Indeed, if I do a deep copy with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent))` as :

```
// Global variables : Player white and black
var playerWhite = ['white', 'black'];
var playerBlack = ['black', 'white'];

//Global variable Hit 
var Hit = {
 currentPlayer: playerBlack,
 coordPlayable: ['0', '0'],
 coordCurrent: ['0', '0'],
};

function recursive_function(HitCurrent, depth) {

// Deep copy
var HitTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent));

// Switch color for player

// BEFORE
console.log('BEFORE = ', HitTemp.currentPlayer);

// Switch
HitTemp.currentPlayer = (HitTemp.currentPlayer == playerBlack) ? playerWhite : playerBlack;

// AFTER : expected the opposite of BEFORE
console.log('AFTER = ', HitTemp.currentPlayer);

...
}
```

and I get with `BEFORE` and `AFTER` :

```
BEFORE =  
Array [ "black", "white" ]

AFTER =  
Array [ "black", "white" ]
```

As you can see, the value of "HitTemp.currentPlayer" is **not switched**, it seems that "`HitTemp.currentPlayer == playerBlack`" is set to **false** whereas the "`BEFORE`" value of "`HitTemp.currentPlayer`" is set to "`playerBlack`".

I must make notice that `recursive_function` is called with the global object `Hit` in the `main(`) like :

```
    //Global variable Hit 
    var Hit = {
     currentPlayer: playerBlack,
     coordPlayable: ['0', '0'],
     coordCurrent: ['0', '0'],
    };

    // Main function
    function main() {

        recursive_function(Hit, maxDepth);
    ...

    }
```

Has this issue a relation with the **deep copy** of `HitCurrent` to `HitTemp` object ?

**UPDATE 2:**

If I use only one "=" (and not two "==") like this :

```
console.log('BEFORE = ', HitTemp.currentPlayer);
HitTemp.currentPlayer = (HitTemp.currentPlayer = playerBlack) ? playerWhite : playerBlack;
console.log('AFTER = ', HitTemp.currentPlayer);
```

Then the switching works : What's the right syntax (one "=" symbol or two ) with the condition of ternary operator to test an equality ?

Comment: Does your C code do a shallow copy or a deep copy?

Comment: -@Andy Gaskell . I think that C code performs a deep copy between **game** and **game2** arrays and Ideally, I would like to clone the object **Hit** since I want to have the current state of game for each recursive call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN Object.assign()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

> Warning for Deep Clone
>
> For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because
>   Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a
>   reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

In your case the `currentPlayer: playerBlack` is not deep copied.

Solutions like :

```
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Have been advised here : [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript?rq=1)

Regarding **UPDATE 1** : you compare two differents objects, they are copies with same values, but different objects in memory. Try to only compare strings or integers to differentiates your players. – Siltaar 2 mins ago   edit

Regardine **UPDATE 2** : the syntax with only one equal sign "=" is an attribution statement. Attribution usually return true. You're trying to make a comparison, so I would recommande to stick with "==" or "===" (if object type matters).

Comment: -@Siltaar . thanks for your answer but having another problem with your solution, could you see please my **UPDATE 1** and **UPDATE 2** ? regards

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign performs a shallow copy. Based on your comment above it looks like you want a deep copy. If you know that this data structure will not change then something like this will work:

```
var HitTemp = Object.assign({}, Hit, {
    coordPlayable: Hit.coordPlayable.slice(0),
    coordCurrent: Hit.coordCurrent.slice(0)
});
```

If you want a cleaner, more general solution check out [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#cloneDeep) from lodash. Since this is a game and performance may be a concern this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/10916838) is worth checking out.

Comment: As an extra note, although it may be less readable, we could also use `Object.assign` with arrays. `coordPlayable: Object.assign([], Hit.coordPlayable)`